# image appears in dialogflow chatbot but not shown in whatsapp chatbot and making twilio error

Tags: image, twilio, dialogflow-es, chatbot, whatsapp

> see update: Partial Solution

I'm using dailogflow and twilio to make whatsapp chatbot.

Text messages appears normally in both dialogflow and whatsapp.

Images appears only in dialogflow chatbot, but it is not working in whatsapp chatbot and makes error in twilio

This is the part of code which I'm adding to Inline Editor of DialogFlow fulfillment:

```
    agent.add(new Card({
         title: `Title: this is a card title`,
         imageUrl: 'http://examplesitelink.com/image_name.png',
       })
```

below the error message which I receive in twilio

```
MESSAGE
The URI scheme, of the URI null, must be equal (ignoring case) to 'http', 'https', 'ws', or 'wss'
......
HTTP retrieval failure
......
Possible Causes
Web server returned a 4xx or 5xx HTTP response to Twilio
Misconfigured Web Server
Network disruptions between Twilio and your web server
No Content-Type header attached to response
Content-Type doesn't match actual content, e.g. an MP3 file that is being served with Content-Type: audio/x-wav, instead of Content-Type: audio/mpeg
```

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

---

> Partial Solution

Below a partial solution

I became able to send images to whats app via dialogflow fulfillment

First, in the 'package.json' I added twilio in dependencies, "twilio": "3.37.1" (check the latest version on npm twilio)

Second I added below code to send an image to whatsapp using its url, and it works

```js
const client = require('twilio')('YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID', 'YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN'); /* change YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID and YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN to your own twilio account data */

    client.messages
        .create({
            to: 'whatsapp:+13233633791', /* change it to your the number which you want to send the image to*/ 
            from: 'whatsapp:+18007778888', /* change it to your the number which twilio sandbox provide, you can find it here: https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/whatsapp/sandbox */
            body: "Hi Joe! Please find your boarding pass attached. Flight OA2345 departs at 11 pm PST.",
            mediaUrl: 'https://emerald-coral-3661.twil.io/assets/2-OwlAir-Upcoming-Trip.PNG',
        })
        .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
```

> the problem now is:

In previous code, `to` is required, which means I have to specify the number which I want to send the image to, that looks odd, but the code will not work if I didn't specify `to`.

What I need to know is, how can I change: `to: 'whatsapp:+13233633791',` to any code  can send the message to the `current user who use whatsapp`

Comment: Cards are not supported with every platform - you can find out more at https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-rich-messages#card

Comment: Thanks for your response, is there a way to insert images without card?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem of not being able to send the media messages to any user that is using the chatbot currently. I found the solution to that in a youtube video, in which they have extracted the receiver mobile no. from the request object like below -

```
const data = request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload;
const To = data.From;
const From = data.To;
```

Here the request object is the one you get when you create your dialogflow agent using the code below 'req' here-

```
app.post("/", express.json(), (req, res) => {
    -------------------
    -------------------
    function handler() {
         ----------
    }
    intentMap.set("intent", handler);

}
```